# How to make a class visible for RSpec test file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have model Player, which lies in app/models:

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  ...
end
```

I'm using gem `rspec-rails` and I have file with a test that determines if player is successfully created, which lies in test/models:

```
require 'rspec'

require_relative '../../app/models/player.rb'

RSpec.describe 'Player' do           
  it 'saves new player' do
    expect(Player.new.save).to eq true
  end
end
```

I'm getting error NameError: uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord. This is probably because test classes don't see model classes. How to make them visible and avoid error, making possible to test creation of new player?

Comment: With the correct setup of rspec, you don't have to `require` the model files at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `require 'rails_helper'` to your spec at the top of the file. You can remove all other "requires".

Docs: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/4-0/docs/model-specs

Comment: Why this is required (no pun intended): RSpec doesn't know anything about your Rails environment; `rails_helper` is the typical convention that has a `require` statement inside it that loads your Rails app, and all the magic that goes with it.